# Problema en código, ayuda para mostrar todos los componentes en localhost

Tags: php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    require_once 'core/models/class.Autoload.php';
    Autoload::load();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>GoalManager - online football manager - fútbol manager online</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="GoalManager is a strategy soccer game, in which you have the posibility to convert your virtual currency into real money."/>
        <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="GMO1/libs/images/icon.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="GMO1/libs/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="GMO1/libs/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="GMO1/libs/css/field.css">
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
        <script src="GMO1/libs/js/functions.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'UA-102117334-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['user_fmo']))
            {
                if(!isset($_SESSION['user_fmo_id']))
                {
                    session_destroy();
                    header('location: https://goalmanageronline.com/');
                }
                if(isset($_GET['referral']))
                {
                    header('location: https://goalmanageronline.com/');
                }
                include_once 'core/modules/user_menu.php';
                echo '<div class="container dashboard-content"><div class="row">';
                if(isset($_GET['module']))
                {
                    $module_name=strtolower($_GET['module']);
                    if(!in_array($module_name, array('formation','inbox')))
                    {
                        include_once 'core/modules/side_userbar.php';
            include_once 'core/modules/formation_modal.php';
                    }
                    if(in_array($module_name, array('side_userbar','user_menu','register','modals','menu_register','404')))
                    {
                        header('location: index.php');
                    }
                    $path="core/modules/".$module_name.".php";
                    if(file_exists($path))
                    {
                        include_once $path;
                        unset($path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unset($path);
                        include_once 'core/modules/error.php';
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    include_once 'core/modules/side_userbar.php';
                    include_once 'core/modules/formation_modal.php';
                    include_once 'core/modules/dashboard.php';
                }
                echo '</div></div>';
            }
            else
            {
        if(isset($_GET['module']))
                {
                    header('location:index.php');
                }
        include("core/modules/register.php");
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Este código es el del index, en la web online aparecía la tabla de ranking de equipos, y también en el centro aparecía el registro de usuario, pero ahora sólo me aparece el index con la imagen de fondo y los logos, pero nada de esos módulos, hay algo llamado mal? hay algo extra? alguna mano? el problema fue al querer trabajar en localhost y descargar los archivos de aws, también descargué la base de datos mysql  y fue exportada a localhost, si necesitan algún dato más por favor indíquenlo, soy principiante en php y este proyecto es mío, lo hizo un programador del cual ya no tengo contacto, es un proyecto grande y me gustaría verlo funcionar en localhost, así puedo ir conociéndolo más de lleno al código e ir actualizandolo.

Comment: pregunta para empezar, tus modulos ahora apuntan a tu db local no? cambiaste todo eso?

Comment: Buenos dias, intente ponerle la url completa de local host include("http://localhost/GMO1/core/modules/register.php");

Comment: .- Pero al hacerlo en todos los include, el server me lanza este error .- Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\index.php on line 4

Warning: require_once(http://localhost/GMO1/core/models/class.Autoload.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\index.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/GMO1/core/models/class.Autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\GMO1\index.php on line 4

Comment: Y si intento entrar a la url esa, por ejemplo http://localhost/GMO1/core/modules/user_menu.php,. me aparece lo sig "¡Error del servidor!
Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor y no se ha podido completar su solicitud. Se ha producido un error interno en el servidor y no se ha podido completar su solicitud. O el servidor está sobrecargado o ha habido un fallo en la ejecución de un programa CGI.

Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.

Error 500"

Comment: Si mantenes la misma estructura de carpetas en tu localhost esas rutas no deberian cambiar. Yo pregunte por la conexion a la base de datos

Comment: class Connection extends mysqli
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        @parent::__construct('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'goalma5_gmo', '3306');

Comment: esa connection a la base de dato tengo, puse el ip de localhost, el user por default, nombre de la db y el puerto

Comment: Y si esta corriendo el server de Base de datos?, puedes probarlo usando algun manejador de base de datos.

Comment: Lo probe usando mysqlworkbench y me abre todo bien